# Can submit different namespace in vxml

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs, vxml

Can submit different namespace in vxml, this is example vxml code.

```
<filled namelist="getSendDay getSendTime getSentMonth">
        <submit next="{}" namelist="getSendDay getSendTime getSentMonth" method="get" />
</filled>
```

How to catch this different namespace in Restful(Jax-Rs) web service? this value passing way is correct?  ( I an looking for Java answer ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are when submit in namelist category pass into web service a value like this...

```
{url}/hello/param?getSendDay=12&getSendTime=18:30&getSentMonth=05
```

this can be caught in restful web service using the java class below:

```
@Path("/hello")
public class HelloWorldService {

    @GET
    @Path("/param")
    public Response getMsg(@Context UriInfo urlInfo) {

        String Day = urlInfo.getQueryParameters().getFirst("getSendDay"); //getSendDay getSendTime getSendMonth
        String Time = urlInfo.getQueryParameters().getFirst("getSendTime");
        String Month = urlInfo.getQueryParameters().getFirst("getSendMonth");


        String output = "Jersey say : Month is " + Month + ", Day is " + Day + " and Time is " + Time;

        return Response.status(200).entity(output).build();

    }

}
```